# Compilador de C++

Tags: c++

Estou iniciando o curso de Sistema de Informação e gostaria de saber qual compilador e melhor para utilizar, pois o professor passou vários e não especificou qual é melhor?

Comment: Começando o curso com uma linguagem orientada a objeto? Puxado hein...

Comment: Apesar da resposta a esta pergunta ser uma opinião (que não é considerado muito legal no SO-pt): g++ http://gcc.gnu.org/

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU que roda no Mac OS X, no Linux, no Free BSD e no Windows (a implementação MinGW é a mais facil de usar). Você pode usar a IDE Eclipse que tem uma distribuição para desenvolvedores C e C++ que se chama [CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) - clique no link [Eclipse C/C++ IDE for Kepler SR2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/keplersr2) para download da IDE.

Veja a observação abaixo que especifica como fazer o Eclipse CDT reconhecer a instalação do MinGW

> CDT will find your MinGW install automatically if you install it into **C:\MinGW** and **add** the **C:\MinGW\bin** directory to your **PATH**, or set the MINGW_HOME environment variable to the install location.

O MinGW pode ser encontrado aqui : [Download do MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download)

Depois de fazer o download e executar o setup você poderá executar o comando abaixo para instalar o compilador C++

```
mingw-get install gcc
```

O `mingw-get` é o gerenciador de pacotes do MinGW e facilita a vida do desenvolvedor na tarefa de instalar as versões corretas das ferramentas de desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de vários fatores, como para que plataforma e processador você quer? Considerando que você quer compilar para PC, se você estiver no Linux, eu indicaria certamente o g++ para C++ e o gcc para C, agora no Windows o MinGW apresenta o melhor custo beneficio, pois é free, e seria o g++ para Windows, o compilador da Microsoft o Visual C++, note que tanto a IDE quanto o compilador chama Visual C++ gera um código mais otimizado no entanto ele é pago, por isso para mim o MinGW é melhor, pois tem um custo beneficio ótimo, e resolve todos os problemas.